# Limiting Scope of Post with Facebook API

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently using the Facebook API in a laravel package. I would like to programmatically edit who can see posts that I send out. Facebook provides this option for users simply trying to post a status, and users can simply edit "who can see this?". I have not seen much in the documentation that would allow me to edit this very same option in my code. I would greatly appreciate any insight about this.I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Check the privacy parameter in the documentation for user/feed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your response @CBroe